# Free/open source ASP.NET gridview control

Tags: jquery, gridview

Does anyone know where I can find some pretty good Gridview controls for ASP.NET?  I'm am really trying to avoid using the standard grids. Any help would be appreciated.

TIA

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid the standard ASP.NET controls?

Comment: Just wanting to use something different that will allow for either json data etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try Telerik's controls. They have a set of free controls, and others you need to pay for. I think they're considered to be one of the best. http://www.telerik.com/community/free-products.aspx